# Image field in custom entity

Tags: 7, views, entities, media

I have a custom entity with an icon_fid property. This property is used to store images.

When displaying this field in views, it just shows up as a number (the file id)

I would like to display the standard image formatter for this.

There seems to be a handler for user picture, but no generic handler for images. I have tried the file_filemime handler, but this is different.

Setting the property type to image using hook_entity_property_info_alter does not seem to work at all (broken/missing handler)

I am hoping there is some magic property somewhere that'll work. I want views to display the standard image field options (image style and all of that)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you define the property `icon_fid` as a __file__ `type` within your [`hook_entity_property_info`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7)? That should leave you with a Views relationship (in the advanced section), where you can join in the file data. That should provide you with more options.

Comment: It gives me the file details like extension, file name and so on. I guess worst case, I could embed it into a html field. I'd rather the image get rendered directly by views, but this would be a reasonable backup plan. Thank you.

Comment: I was assuming you'd also get a field `File: Rendered File` or `File: Rendered` to display the file. But it could be I have those options as a result of another module...